# Data API : ValueError: `y` argument is not supported when using dataset as input

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I have 45000 images of size 224*224, stored as a numpy array. This array, called `source_arr` has shape 45000,224,224 and it fits in the memory.

I divide this array into train, test and validate array and pre-process (normalize and convert greyscale to 3 channels RGB) them using tf.data API.

I have written a pre process function like:

```
def pre_process(x):
     x_norm = (x - mean_Rot_MIP) / Var_Rot_MIP
     # Stacking along the last dimension to avoid having to move channel axis
     x_norm_3ch = tf.stack((x_norm, x_norm, x_norm), axis=-1)
     return x_norm_3ch
```

`X_train_cases_idx.idx` contains the index of images from `source_arr` that are part of training data.

I have read the corresponding training images from `source_arr` in the dataset object like:

```
X_train = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices([source_arr[i] for i in X_train_cases_idx.idx])
```

And then I apply the pre_process function on the training images like
`X_train = X_train.map(pre_process)`

This is a multiclass classification problem, thus I convert the label variable y into 1 hot encoding like:

```
lb = LabelBinarizer()
y_train = lb.fit_transform(y_train)
```

The length of X_train and y_train are 36000

I perform the model.fit operation on RESNET50 like:

```
H = model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size = BS, validation_data=(X_val, y_val), epochs = NUM_EPOCHS, shuffle =False)
```

and I get an error:

```
ValueError: `y` argument is not supported when using dataset as input.
```

I understand that I need to pass the X_train and y_train both as a tuple in the Dataset object.
**How can I do that?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have source_arr and y_train as numpy array ;so you can do :

```
data_set = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(  (source_arr , y_train) )
```

if you have source_arr and y_train as tf.dataset :

```
data_set = tf.data.Dataset.zip( (source_arr , y_train) )
```

Comment: I tried the 1st option, as both the `source_arr` and `y_train` are np array. But i get the error: ```from_tensor_slices() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given```

Comment: even with tuple parentheses ?   (    (   source_arr , y_train     )   )

Comment: I converted both the `source_arr` and `y_train` into tensors and used the 2nd option. That worked. Thanks!

Comment: It works for me too. I tried to pass another dataset with images (so x and y are images) instead of labels (y) but had to zip them first! so the second code worked as I already had them as datasets.